# Magento does not pass empty varible in POST data

Tags: magento-1.9, post-data

I am using Magento community and I have below problem.
I have created a module which adds a product to customer groups. I have added checkboxes for all the customer groups in a tab using Ajax tab using code..

```
<?php foreach ($group as $eachGroup) { ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="productgroup[]" value="<?php echo $eachGroup->getCustomerGroupId(); ?>" <?php if(in_array($eachGroup->getCustomerGroupId(),$existGroupProduct)){ ?> checked="checked" <?php } ?>>
<?php } ?>
```

When I select a customer group, it saves the data. When I edit my selected values it works fine.

Now when I try to remove all the groups by unselecting all checkboxes, it is not working. I have checked my variable using below conditions but none works.

```
isset($_POST['productgroup'])
..
empty($_POST['productgroup'])
```

If I set the value of the array as null in my function it also resets my customer groups value if I have not opened my "Customer Group" tab and I save the product.

Answer (score 1):

Try bellow code

```
if(isset($_POST['productgroup']) && is_array($_POST['productgroup'])) {
    $_POST['productgroup'] = $_POST['productgroup'];
}else {
    $_POST['productgroup'] = array();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Abdul, My question is the variable, "productgroup" is not being passed as null to POST data when I unselect all checkboxes. I think it should passed as ['productgroup']=>Array(), but its not.

Comment: yes it is not pass if your unselect all checkboxes

Comment: And if I don't go to my tab and save the product, it also does not pass to POST data, again resetting my data, which is wrong.

Comment: if your try echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);

Comment: If your not selected checkboxe & radio button then your data is not post

Comment: I cant find my variable in $_POST data with both conditions: 1) When I unselect all checkboxes. 2) When I do not open My tab and save the product. It should be passed as Array() when I unselect all checkboxes. Do I make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34469/discussion-between-john-and-abdul).